# Why am i getting -9.255 included in the output?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, structure

I am trying to print out the 2 employees which one member contains a multidimensional array.

```
    struct Employees{
    string name;
    double salary;
    char skill[5][20];
 };
void main(){
Employees Namn[3] = {
    { "Dawn", 120000, { "C#", "C++" } },
    { "John", 13456, { "Java", "C++" } }
};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    cout << Namn[i].name << "\t";
    cout << Namn[i].salary;
    cout << "\t";
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
            cout << Namn[i].skill[j][k];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am trying to print out the 2 employees` And yet you're printing out 3 `Employees` in your code.

Comment: Why do you allocate space for 3 employees but only provide data for 2?  Turn the warning levels up to maximum on your compiler / IDE.  You should have received a warning for this issue.

Comment: In your initialization of the array, your are missing some skills.  You should provide the missing skills (such as empty strings) and don't rely on the compiler to provide default values.

Comment: **Big Question**:  Why do you use `std::string` for the name but use `char` for the skills?  I suggest you use an array of `std::string` for the names and drop the `char` type.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Never saw the compiler complain about *too few initializers* in that situation yet.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: There's nothing wrong with relying on the compiler to provide default values. Unspecified members are initialized to zero. For `char` arrays, that means all elements are set to `'\0'`, which means they contain empty strings. (The loop that displays the values should probably be checking for that, though.)

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect; it should be `int main()`. Did your compiler not complain about that?

Comment: @KeithThompson:  After being in maintenance for decades, and working on safety critical systems, I find that being explicit reduces a lot of defects.

Comment: @user657267 I am sorry but i left that empty so that it can get default values.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: If you give a number, you are being explicit that you want the rest zeroed out. Otherwise, just let the compiler figure out how many you wrote. Trust it not to mis-count. If you want to double-check some constant, use `static_assert`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am using string for the name because i dont really care abt that. I just wanted to use char so that i can learn how to play with the multidimensional array. That is the only thing that is important here.

Comment: @KeithThompson void main() can be used if you dont want a return value..

Comment: @hugryclide: Not legally. The C++ standard explicitly requires `main` to return `int`. If you don't want a return value, you don't need a `return` statement; reaching the closing `}` does an implicit `return 0;`. Again, did your compiler really not complain about that?

Comment: @KeithThompson It didn't complain aboutt that, and I know it is not standard, but my instructor likes using that, so i use it aswell.

Comment: @all Thanks for your help, I guess the issue was with the default values.

Comment: Your instructor is giving you bad advice.

Answer (score -1):

The -9.255 output is caused by the default values. I just needed to add { "0", 0.0, { "0", "0" } }. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: In debug mode, memory is usually filled with hex cccccccccccccccc and hex cccccccccccccccc when interpreted as a double is -9.2559631349317831 x 10^061

Comment: When you initialize a struct using `{ }`, any unlisted members must be value-initialized (which means initialized to `0.0` for a double);  so if this is really the answer then your compiler is extremely broken

Comment: To know why it initializes uninitialized values to 0xCC read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)